# How to get templated class member function differentiation based on type?

Tags: c++, templates, polymorphism

I have the following situation(simplified from my actual problem):

```
// In Tree.hpp
template <class T>
class Tree : public Plant {
    ...
    
    // Returns true if valid for purposes
    bool valid() const override;

}
```

The template parameter can be either a Deciduous or Coniferous, or a child of those types such as Pine or Oak.

I would like to differentiate valid() based on whether the templated parameter is Deciduous or a child, or Coniferous or a child, meaning two versions.

```
// In Tree.cpp
template<>
bool Tree<Coniferous>::valid() const {
    //Coniferous valid logic
}

template<>
bool Tree<Deciduous>::valid() const {
    //Deciduous valid logic
}
```

This does not work, as I get errors such as:

```
libForest.so: undefined reference to `Tree<Pine>::valid() const'
libForest.so: undefined reference to `Tree<Oak>::valid() const'
```

What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: Reopened, because there are explicit specializations here for which the duplicate suggestion that templates must be implemented in the header does not apply.

Answer (score 1):

Your explicit specializations for the `Deciduous` and `Coniferous` are correct. But they are specializations explicitly only for when the template argument is one of *exactly* these types.

If you want to include derived classes, then you want a *partial* specialization which specializes on a category of types based on some condition.

Unfortunately you can't partially specialize a member of a class template (as a partial specialization on the class template's template arguments). Instead you must partially specialize the *whole* class for the two categories of types.

Since that is probably not what you want to do, I would suggest some approach other than specialization. For example since C++17 you can write:

```
// In Tree.hpp
template <class T>
class Tree : public Plant {
    ...
    
    // Returns true if valid for purposes
    bool valid() const override {
        if constexpr(std::is_base_of_v<Coniferous, T>) {
            // Coniferous valid logic
        } else /*if constexpr(std::is_base_of_v<Deciduous, T>)*/ {
            // Deciduous valid logic
        } /* else { ... } */
    }
};
```

However, with the limited explanation you gave of your code it seems weird that you have inheritance with a `virtual` function interface on the one hand for `Plant` and `Tree`, but what seem to be more specific subclass like `Oak` then suddenly become a template parameter instead of a subclass? Maybe reconsider whether this is really what you want.

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately I don't have the option of using the C++17 solution. In C++11 the only solution then would be to define a valid() function for each possible derived class of Deciduous/Coniferous?